# Как в Android над Activity с OpenGL поместить слой с полями для ввода текста?

Tags: android, activity, opengl

Добрый день. Собственно такая вот у меня проблема. Есть Activity с OpenGL. Всё рендерится замечательно. Большинство функций вынесено в библиотеку и методы помечены, как native. Но вот в определенный момент мне бы хотелось, чтобы пользователь мог ввести данные: логин, пароль. Эти данные используются для идентификации. Уже почти неделю бьюсь, никак не могу ничего толкового придумать.

Comment: Приветствую!. Такие-же проблемы. На форуме PowerVR и в новостных группах NDK видел пару таких тредов. Говорят что нужно вставлять вторую обычную activity поверх первой native activity и перекачивать из нее через JNI ввод пользователя. Тем не менее рабочего решения/примера никто так и не оставил. Если найдете какое-нибудь решение оставьте пруфлинк в треде пожалуйста.

Comment: Я сначала думал в лоб запрограммировать текстовое окно и клавиатуру в native activity, но потом понял что с выводом рекламы мне все равно не справится и решил подождать пока найдется нормальное решение для этого вопроса.

Comment: http://forum.imgtec.com/discussion/2228/how-to-add-android-gui-view-over-nativeactivity

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-ndk/NnunePFoeYg

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/r25fbnrJ0eo

Еще на хабре кто-то это проделал, но они использовали Marmalade там не пахнет native activity.
http://habrahabr.ru/post/124077/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак не пойму почему нельзя просто поднять поверх еще 1 активити. Прозрачную по бокам и с диалог боксом в центре?

[Пример](http://psdreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Login-Modal-Dialog-Window-with-CSS-and-jQuery-thumbnail.jpg)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(openGLactivity, YourLoginPasswordActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
openGLactivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: А можно это как-то через NDK сделать? У меня просто кросс-платформенный движок. Для платформы iOS нужный функционал реализован в создании прозрачного UiView поверх OpenGL и я на этот UiView ложу в нужный момент нужные мне текстовые поля или поля для ввода. Потому что нужны они мне как для создания экрана Регистрации, так и для ввода логина и пароля уже зарегистрированный учетки. Вот и пытаюсь найти решение для Андроида, которое было бы подходящим. То есть мне нужно через NDK управлять прозрачным слоем и динамически создавать на нем нужный контент.

Comment: Зачем Вам NDK для этого? у вас есть активити - в нем делайте что угодно прозрачное.

Comment: К сожалению, необходимо это делать через NDK, потому что движок кроссплатформенный и будет использоваться и в других проектах (играх).

Comment: 1) Скиньте ссылку на движок или название. Я уверен вас спасет создание прозрачного слоя на этом движке.
2) Не все части могут быть кроссплатформенными, хоть и стремиться к этому нужно не стоит забывать, что есть различия в платформах.

Comment: Движок самописный, эксклюзивный. :-) Работаю в компании, поэтому ссылки дать не могу - секрет фирмы. Просто весь код всей игры написан на C++, поэтому текстовые поля, поля для ввода на определенных экранах созданы не родные для каждой платформы, а "движковые". А вот в самом движке эти инпуты компилируются наследуясь от нативных для каждой платформы. Мнгое обернуто макросами #ifdef.
Вот поэтому мне нужно это делать через NDK.

Comment: Либо как у я уже говорил делайте слой на уровне движка, либо ищите нужные классы тут например - http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/

Comment: В общем, посовещавшись с начальством и т.п. было решено создать второй слой прозрачный. А вот взаимодействие между ними будет реализоваться как NDK-методами, так и SDK. Частично помогла вот эта статья: http://idev.by/android/22971/